# PHP Error logging on Apache HTTPD on Windows: What is wrong with this configuration that it is not logging errors?

Tags: php, httpd.conf

I am getting a blank screen and nothing in the error logs for a php program I am trying to get up and running (it happens to be yourls).  What do I need to do to get error logging enabled or to otherwise get an indicate of why the page is not loading (I know there are multiple postings on this but none of the fixes suggested in this posts seems to generate any output and don't seem to work for this specific implementation)?

I'm running php from this install: php-8.0.0-nts-Win32-vs16-x64.zip

I'm running Apache HTTPD from this install: httpd-2.4.46-o111i-x64-vc15.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a behavior of the yourls software I was trying to run.  It had a flag that turned error logging/messaging off AND it was not compatable with php 8.  I switched to php 7 and switched to the php.ini-development config (by renaming it to php.ini) and I am now seeing error messages (the driver for the database is missing).